# Acceder a virtual host desde LAN

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Estoy intentando acceder a un virtual host que tengo configurado en un servidor fedora desde otro ordenador mi lan con `xip.io`

Mi fichero `/etc/httpd/conf.d/xxx.conf` contiene lo siguiente:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx
ServerName xxx
ServerAlias xxx.*.xip.io
</VirtualHost>
```

El fichero `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` está configurado por defecto y en el fichero `/etc/hosts` tengo añadida la siguiente linea

```
127.0.0.1   xxx
```

No sé donde tengo el fallo, pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar de ninguna manera para que me acceda a la web del proyecto. En un principio con `http://xxx.ip-servidor.xip.io/` ya debería poder acceder a la web, pero no llega a conectarse a ningún sitio.

Edit. Estos son los errores que me muestra el log de apache

```
[Fri Jan 12 16:28:55.440153 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6188] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Fri Jan 12 16:28:56.776160 2018] [suexec:notice] [pid 6241] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Jan 12 16:28:56.910534 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 6241] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Jan 12 16:28:56.910654 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 6241] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Fri Jan 12 16:28:56.910672 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 6241] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Fri Jan 12 16:28:56.961926 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6241] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Fedora) SVN/1.9.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 12 16:28:56.962079 2018] [core:notice] [pid 6241] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: ¿Pero debería escribirla solo con el nombre del servidor o toda la url entera tipo xxx.*.xip.io? Más que nada porque he probado de las dos maneras y no me conecta. ¿Debo hacer alguna configuración extra en los clientes?

Comment: Perdona @JackNavaRow, pero debo estar ya de fin de semana, que no me aclaro. Entiendo que hosts resuelve la direccion ip a través del nombre. 

Por ejemplo 192.168.2.225   proyecto.dev.

En este caso, accedería a dicha url. Y allí, el archivo de virual host debería resolver a donde debe dirigir el acceso, ¿no?

Comment: Si accedo por ip tampoco accedo a ningún sitio

Comment: Estado activo. Y si hago un ping desde el cliente me envía todos los paquetes.

Comment: El log de access me aparece vacío, en cambio en el de error si que me aparecen errores, aunque como si me estuvieran hablando en chino...

Comment: Si no tienes un servicio de resolución de nombres en tu LAN, asumo que estás escribiendo en el fichero host de cada PC de la red local desde donde quieres acceder.

Answer (score 0):

Por favor cuando creas virtualhost no debes hacer nada con `httpd.conf` ,
debes hacer lo siguiente

crea un virtualhost en la carpeta `/etc/apache/site-available/` el nombre deberia ser algo como `tusitio.conf` asumiendo que tu sitio es `xip` lo ideal es crearlo asi `xip.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName xip.io
  ServerAlias www.xip.io
  DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx
  <Directory "/var/www/xxx">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

ejecuta el comando para agregar tu virtualhost a apache2

```
sudo a2ensite xip.conf
```

y luego debes reiniciar el sitio

```
sudo apache2 restart
```

si por alguna razon quieres bajar el sitio por defecto de apache debes ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
sudo a2dissite default.conf
```

Comment: `a2??site` son comandos disponibles en derivados de Debian. Para derivados de Red Hat -como Fedora- el primer lugar donde buscamos archivos de configuración es en `conf.d`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Has un telnet IP-Servidor Puerto, por ejemplo:

```
$ telnet 192.168.100.4 80
Trying 192.168.100.4...
Connected to 192.168.100.4.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Y debes ver un mensaje como el de arriba si pasado unos minutos no se conecta entonces el muro cortafuegos esta bloqueando el acceso a tu sitio puedes hacer los siguiente:

2) Desactivar el muro cortafuegos (No recomendable en servidores de producción o de cara a Internet)

```
$ sudo systemctl stop firewalld
$ sudo systemctl disable firewalld (Impide que se inicie el muro cortafuegos al iniciar el SO)
```

3) Añadir al muro cortafuegos el rango de IPs que tendrán acceso al servidor web (Opción recomendable)

```
$ sudo  firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-source=192.168.0.0/24 (Pon tu rango de IPs de tu LAN)
```

Refrescar las reglas del muro cortafuegos

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

[1] https://www.librebyte.net/apache/instalar-y-configurar-apache-http-server/